# How to add command action to 'open with ...'  on OS X

Tags: macos, finder, automator

In Finder, using the 'Open With' in mouse right click menu, I want to open a text file using the command `xterm -e vim`.

Could anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: What is the "right menu"? Are you sure you don't want to add it to the wrong menu?

Comment: sorry, it is 'mouse right click menu',  'open with...'

Answer (score 3):

Create an new Cocoa Application project.

- Add this code to your application delegate .m file:

.

```
- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)theApplication openFile:(NSString *)filename {

    [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/X11/bin/xterm" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-e", @"/usr/bin/vim", filename, nil]];
    exit(0);

    return YES;
}
```

- Configure your app as a background only application by adding the key `LSBackgroundOnly` to your plist file and set its value to YES:

  ```
  <key>LSBackgroundOnly</key>
  <true/>
  ```
- Register as being able to open text file by adding this to your plist:

  ```
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
          <string>Plain text document</string>
          <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
          <array>
              <string>text</string>
              <string>txt</string>
              <string>utf8</string>
          </array>
          <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
          <string>TEXT</string>
          <key>CFBundleTypeMIMETypes</key>
          <array>
              <string>text/plain</string>
          </array>
          <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
          <array>
              <string>TEXT</string>
              <string>sEXT</string>
              <string>ttro</string>
          </array>
      </dict>
  ```
- Open your MainMenu.xib, and uncheck the option "Visible at Launch" of your window.

You are done. Build. You might need to open it once with Finder to make Launch Services aware of it.

Then, in the Finder, you can right-click on a text file, and in the "Open With..." menu, select your app, like in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: XTerm? Old school. I'd use a Terminal.app .term file. http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2002/03/26/terminal_four.html?page=3